# Rest .next()? My click function adding '.active' twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

If you take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQabJ/11/) it will seem fine, but if you click next and move down 2 to 3 times, and then click "memory" (in top nav) it takes `.active` back to the first `.item`,

then if you click 'NEXT' again it continues to go to the next element from the prior one we left off of.

I am trying to reset it and continue based on where we go after clicking on the top nav.

**Faulty jQuery:*** Two click functions both adding active*

```
var  items = $('.item'), 
     currentItem = items.filter('.active'), 
     last = items.last();    

 $("#next-button").on('click', function () {
     currentItem.removeClass('active');
     var nextItem = currentItem.next();

    if (nextItem.length) {
        currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
      if (currentItem.is(last)) {
         $('#slide-buttons').addClass('red');
      }
    }
    
    var items = $('.item');
      $(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").click(function () {
       var theID  = $(this).data("id");

items.filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('category') === theID;
}).addClass('active');

});

 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQabJ/11/)

I Googled "how to reset .next() jquery" but couldn't find anything, not sure if that's even the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had was that `currentItem` didn't get updated when you clicked on a breadcrumb.

I made a lot of changes, mostly "streamlining" things. I removed your global variables and based the current item on the `active` class instead. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/kQabJ/17/

```
$("#next-button").on('click', function () {
    var nextItem = $('.active').removeClass('active').next();
    if (!nextItem.length) {
        nextItem = $('.item').first();
    }
    nextItem.addClass('active');
});
$(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").on('click', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    var theID = $(this).data("id");
    $("#" + theID).addClass('active');
});
```

Note that I also modified your DOM a bit to make it easier to select an item when a user clicks a breadcrumb. That change is using an ID on your `.item`s instead of data. This way you can do `$("#" + theID)` rather than filtering based on data.

Since these things are uniquely identifying your `.item` elements themselves - it makes since to use an id anyway, but if this is not what you not you can always change that part back.

Comment: Thanks so much, you know your stuff (all of you guys who answered). I definitely like code more streamlined, you nail-ed it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update `currentItem`, see http://jsfiddle.net/kQabJ/13/

```
$(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").on('click', function () {
     items.removeClass('active');       
     var theID  = $(this).data("id");

     items.filter(function() {
     return $(this).data('category') === theID;
    }).addClass('active');
       currentItem = items.filter('.active');
    });
```

Comment: This answer is really great as well, if @smerny didnt take time to streamline the code I most likely would have went with this, because all I have to do is add one line to update `currentItem`, it never crossed my mind to update currentItem, well on second thought I think I did attempt to update it, but I must have done something weird. Thank the coding gods for stackoverflow and the amazing people who help learners out like me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code
You were not updating the `currentItem`, which was causing the problem.

```
var items = $('.item'),
    currentItem = items.filter('.active'),
    last = items.last();

$("#next-button").on('click', function () {
    currentItem = items.filter('.active');
    var nextItem = currentItem.next();

    currentItem.next().length > 0 ? currentItem.next().addClass('active')
                                   : items.first().addClass('active');
    currentItem.removeClass('active');
});


$(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").on('click', function () {
    items.removeClass('active');
    var theID = $(this).data("id");

    items.filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('category') === theID;
    }).addClass('active');

});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kQabJ/14/)**

Comment: I like this answer, you also caught my error in not updating `currentItem` this is great since it uses my original code and fixes the error, but I am going to have to go with @smerny answer because it was very nice that he/she took time to streamline the code, it's very readable, and personally I dont like using to many variables. You're awesome for taking time to help, and you must really know your stuff 28.9k rep is NO JOKE :)

Comment: Not a problem.. Glad to have helped :) It's all a learning process. Everyone at some point started from the point that you feel you are currently .. Cheers !!